# ¿Como puedo llenar una matriz con los caracteres de un array?

Tags: c

Buenas tardes quería comentarles un problema que tengo, lo que sucede es que estoy intentando meter un arreglo en una matriz de 5x5 pero solo se llena la primera fila y las siguientes filas **se vuelven a repetir**, la idea del código seria llenar la matriz con la frase del arreglo y llenar lo restante con letras aleatorias siempre y cuando esas letras no se encuentren en el arreglo.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento(hasta el momento estoy intentando meter el array en la matriz, aun no intento llenar lo que sobre de la matriz con letras aleatorias):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char mat[5][5]; //tamaño de la matriz
char letras[]="algoritmosyprogra";
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)//para desplazarse por las columnas
    {
        for (j=0;j<5;j++)//para desplazarse por las filas
        {
            mat[i][j]=letras[j];
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)//para desplazarse por las columnas
    {
        for (j=0;j<5;j++)//para desplazarse por las filas
        {
            printf("\t[%c]",mat[i][j]);//imprime elemento de la matriz en pantalla
        }
      printf("\n\n");//para dejar espacios entre filas.
    }
}
```

Comment: Debes inicializar los contadores i y j en cero. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... y las siguientes filas se vuelven a repetir.

Claro. Estás tomando los valores desde `letras` basándote **unicamente en la columna**:

```
mat[i][j]=letras[j] // <-- usas j como índice
```

Para tomar la letra necesaria, una manera sencilla es utilizar una variable adicional:

```
int i, j, letrasIdx = 0;

for( i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
    for( j = 0; j < 5; ++j ) {
        mat[i][j]=letras[letrasIdx];
        ++letrasIdx;
    }
}
```

de forma que el índice utilizado en `letras` sea independiente de la fila y columna actual.